# How to detect method calls in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging

I'm wondering if there is any way to log all method calls in iOS app? I know that I can add NSLog in every method which call I want to log, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way? For example some internal mechanism which allow me to hook to all methods calls and fire some method/macro in that case. I simple words, how to catch method call and invoke other method before it? Is it even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7224032/1138900

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that only for a couple of classes, then I think you could use the decorator pattern with `NSProxy`.

Answer (score 0):

There is (albeit quite hidden) support for this already:

Just set an environment variable `NSObjcMessageLoggingEnabled` to `YES`

[image]

and look in the file: `/tmp/msgSends-<processID>`

The file should be easy to find if you are using the simulator (I only tested on a Simulator), but may require a jailbroken device to access the output on a device. I'll have a look to see if there is a way to route the output to a user defined file.