# Tracking/Instrumenting events/methods fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, instrumentation

I am trying to print out (e.g., NSLog) the information about events that fired on iPhone application. For example user executes a scenario and I want to track all the methods called and events clicked by the user.

Is there anyway to do that using a category extension and method swizzling features of objective-C to inject some code to log and print the information needed? Right now, I defined a category for UIWindow, UIApplication and UIView. I am not sure where is the best place to track tho, e.g., [UIWindow sendEvent:]? Should I observe objc_msgSend()?

I basically want to instrument a project and inject code with category extension in order to not change the source code as much as possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223555/objective-c-track-all-method-calls ?

Comment: thanks but logging every single call is not practical for my case. I ended up using UIWindow category and method swizzling on [UIWindow sendEvent:]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223555/objective-c-track-all-method-calls