# Understanding the Objective-C event loop

Tags: objective-c, nsrunloop, event-loop

**How can I log every message sent in a single iteration of the Objective-C event loop?**

I want to further my understanding of the Objective-C runtime and thought this would be a good start.

Comment: I think I misread your question. You want a log of all the messages objects are sending to each other?

Comment: @W'rkncacnter I'd just like to see all the events processed in a single iteration of the runLoop (for the main thread for starters). I'm expecting to see something along the lines of "objectA sent this message to objectB, objectC was released...".

Comment: At first I thought you just wanted to do something yourself every iteration. Okay, in that case your answer is already in one of these three questions: [Call a macro any time any method is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783223/), [Break on every method call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961023/), [Track all method calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223555/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions will cause all messages to be logged to a file in /tmp, based on the PID of the process.  Good on simulator, but not on an iDevice.

```
// Start logging all messages
instrumentObjcMessageSends(YES);

// Stop logging all messages
instrumentObjcMessageSends(NO);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`CFRunLoopObserver`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopObserverRef/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001442) opaque type should do exactly what you want. It is

> a general means to receive callbacks at different points within a running run loop.

Use the `activity` argument to [its creation function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopObserverRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001442-CH201-F17726) to specify when you want your observer serviced. For your case, this will probably be either [`kCFRunLoopEntry`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopObserverRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001442-CH3g-C017571) or `kCFRunLoopExit`.

You can get the `CFRunLoopRef` from the current `NSRunLoop`, `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop]`, or by using [`CFRunLoopGetCurrent()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001441-CH201-SW1).